# Cannot push to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with D3.js. The original source sets the `source` and the `target` arrays in the `links` object.

I'm trying to add one more array containing percentages. The technique I follow is the same for source & target.

However, the JavaScript console throws an error - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'percentages' of undefined`

In the code below I've highlighted the statements added for percentages.

```
  function computeNodeLinks() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.sourceLinks = [];
      node.targetLinks = [];
      node.percentages = [];    //**** Added this
    });
    links.forEach(function(link) {
      var source = link.source,
          target = link.target,
          pc = link.pc;    //**** Added this
      if (typeof source === "number") source = link.source = nodes[link.source];
      if (typeof target === "number") target = link.target = nodes[link.target];
      if (typeof pc === "number") pc = link.pc = nodes[link.pc];    //**** Added this
      source.sourceLinks.push(link);
      target.targetLinks.push(link);
      pc.percentages.push(link);    //**** Added this. At this statement I get: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'percentages' of undefined'
    });
  }
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Seems like your "pc", or rather "link.pc" is undefined.

Comment: @HanletEscaño: But `link.source` & `link.target` are defined in the same way..

Comment: Please show us JSON.stringify(links). I think link.pc is undefined.

Comment: @raghavv Well here is the console log of `link` - http://i.imgur.com/D8eAP.png. You're correct that `link.pc` is undefined.

Comment: So you know why some of the link.pc are undefined? Does this solve the issue? If not, post a jsfiddle to work with

Comment: Seeing your console screenshot I've noticed that SOME of your links have the pc Object. Try looking into this: why only some of them have it and others don't ? And my guess your problem is typeof pc === 'number'

Comment: `if (typeof source === "number") { source = link.source = nodes[link.source]; console.log("source here"); }` and do the same thing for `if (typeof pc === "number") {pc = link.pc = nodes[link.pc]; console.log("pc here");}` My guess is that there will be more 'source here' than 'pc here' and this is your problem. not all your pc's are numbers. If so, try a `pc = parceFloat(pc)` before the IFs